# I am getting access token in Header manager and in Request header

Tags: jmeter, correlation

I am new to jmeter. I am getting authorization(access token) in the header manager and request header How should i correlate it
enter image description here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLhbB.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9L35H.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Identify where the token is coming from (most probably as the response to a previous login request)
2. Extract it using a suitable JMeter's [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and save it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html). The choice of the Post-Processor depends on the type of the response, i.e.

   - for HTML it makes sense to go for [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor)
   - for XML or XHTML or where CSS selectors are not too powerful - [XPath2 Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-xpath2-extractor-how-to-achieve-better-correlations)
   - for JSON - [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)
   - for everything else - [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) or [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
3. Replace the hard-coded (recorded?) value with the JMeter Variable from the previous step